# Open source remote sensing and satellite imagery DATA

Tags: remote-sensing, open-source-gis, imagery, satellite, agriculture

What are the most known libraries of open source data related to remote sensing and satellite imagery? Especially applicated to agriculture? And what are their resolutions and frequencies?

Comment: If you seek open data then the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange is likely to be the place to start.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what type of data you are looking for specifically but Earth Explorer is great for Landsat 8 data (https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) or Sentinel online is a great source for any Sentinel data (https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/home).